# Extract all the elements that meet the condition from an XELEMENT var + LINQ to XML

Tags: lambda, linq-to-xml

I have two XELEMENTS `XR` and `XTemp`.

MY `XR` Contains :

```
     <result xmlns="http://abc.com/test">
           <report>
            <unit unit_number="1" id="S1">
                 <classification>Subject</classification>
                 <claim_reported count="0" status="No claims reported" />
            </unit>
           <unit unit_number="2" id="S2">
                <classification>Subject</classification>
                <claim_reported count="0" status="No claims reported" />
           </unit>
        <unit unit_number="3" id="V1">
          <classification>Vehicle</classification>
          <claim_reported count="1" status="Claims reported" />
        </unit>
    ......
     </report>
</result>
```

My `XTemp` contains :

```
 <result xmlns="http://abc.com/test">
   <report>
        <unit unit_number="1" id="S3">
             <classification>Subject</classification>
             <claim_reported count="1" status="Claims reported" />
        </unit>
       <unit unit_number="2" id="S4">
            <classification>Subject</classification>
            <claim_reported count="4" status="Claims reported" />
       </unit>
      <unit unit_number="3" id="V2">
         <classification>Vehicle</classification>
         <claim_reported count="0" status="No claims reported" />
      </unit>
      <unit unit_number="3" id="V3">
         <classification>Vehicle</classification>
         <claim_reported count="2" status="Claims reported" />
      </unit>
         ......
    </report>
 </result>
```

Trying to extract all the `<unit>` elements from `XTemp` based on a certain condtion and add them to `XR`.

The condition is : get all the `<unit>` elements whose id  begins with "V".

Below code was the best I was able to come up with.

But, I get `Object reference not set to an instance` Error.

```
XR.Descendants(xmlns + "unit").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "unit")
  .Where(x => x.Element(xmlns + "unit").Attribute("id").Value.ToUpper().Contains("V")));
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Comment: Would you mind including a snippet of the XML that you're working with as well as the rest of the code that leads up to that line?  Don't make it harder for us to understand your situation, give us the information we need, don't expect us to have to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this bit of code:

```
.Where(x => x.Element(xmlns + "unit").Attribute("id")...
```

At that point in the query you're already querying over `unit` elements. A `unit` doesn't contain a nested `unit`, which is why you get a `NullReferenceException`.

Change it to: `.Where(x => x.Attribute("id")...`

Personally, I find your query hard to read. Firstly, `LastOrDefault` means you potentially expect a null value to exist, yet you're forging ahead with the rest of the query without addressing it. Secondly, you don't need to find the last `unit` element and `AddAfterSelf`. Instead you can directly `Add` to the `report` element and the elements will be appended to the end:

```
var query = xtemp.Descendants(xmlns + "unit")
                 .Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value.StartsWith("V", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

xr.Element(xmlns + "report").Add(query);
```

Also, notice how I checked for "V" while ignoring the case. This is considered best practice as opposed to using `ToUpper`.

---

**EDIT:** based on the comments, here is a solution to sort all the `unit` nodes while preserving the existing order of non-`unit` nodes. This code takes into account whether node occurs before and after existing nodes, or no other nodes at all.

Some assumptions are:

- XR always has `unit` nodes
- IDs follow the existing letter followed by a number format.
- `unit` nodes are kept together and are not interspersed between all other types of nodes.

The first two assumptions are trivial issues to code for if they're incorrect.

```
var query = xtemp.Descendants(xmlns + "unit")
                 .Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value.StartsWith("V", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

var units = xr.Element(xmlns + "report").Elements(xmlns + "unit");
var beforeUnit = units.First().ElementsBeforeSelf().FirstOrDefault();
var afterUnit = units.Last().ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault();

// order based on ID starting letter, then integer value
var orderedUnits = units.Concat(query)
                        .OrderBy(e => e.Attribute("id").Value[0])
                        .ThenBy(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("id").Value.Substring(1)))
                        .ToList();

// remove original unit nodes
units.Remove();

// add ordered units based on their original position
if (beforeUnit != null)
{
    beforeUnit.AddAfterSelf(orderedUnits);
}
else if (afterUnit != null)
{
    afterUnit.AddBeforeSelf(orderedUnits);
}
else
{
    xr.Element(xmlns + "report").Add(orderedUnits);
}
```

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks much. Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I want all the elements whose id's start with "S" appear first followed by the elements whose id's start with "V" in my XR. How can i do that?

Comment: In addition to <unit> elements my <report> might contain other elements also in such case I want to add the extracted <unit> elements only after the last occurence of <unit> element in the XR.

Comment: @BumbleBee the sorting is possible, but your second comment complicates matters a little. If other elements can exist under `<report>` do they *all* need to be sorted alphabetically? Or should existing order be maintained while only the `<unit>` elements get sorted? The former is easier; the latter requires some extra caffeine :)

Comment: @Ahmad thank you.  Only the '<unit>' elements should get sorted while the existing order for the other elements should remain intact.